# Find the max record in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
 question(qid int,title varchar(100))

 answer(aid int,qid int,vote int,content varchar(4096))
```

Qid and aid are primary key.

Each question has some answers, and each answer has an vote number.

Now taking some question qid, how to find the max(vote) answer for each question if the question has some answers?

Ex:

```
mysql> select * from question;
+-----+-------+
| qid | title |
+-----+-------+
|   1 | abc   |
|   2 | efg   |
|   3 | hij   |
|   4 | mn    |
+-----+-------+

mysql> select * from answer;
+-----+------+------+---------+
| aid | qid  | vote | content |
+-----+------+------+---------+
|  77 |    3 |   45 | mysql2  |
| 110 |    1 |   95 | good    |
| 122 |    1 |   78 | bad     |
| 123 |    1 |   34 | bad2    |
| 223 |    2 |   56 | book1   |
| 224 |    2 |   82 | book2   |
+-----+------+------+---------+
```

Now, giving qid(1,2), I want to find the result following:

```
+-----+------+------+---------+
| aid | qid  | vote | content |
+-----+------+------+---------+
| 110 |    1 |   95 | good    |
| 224 |    2 |   82 | book2   |
+-----+------+------+---------+
```

I want the full answer record(with all columns), not only the max(vote) column.

**I just want to show the best answer(the max vote answer) for each question.**

What's the best SQL in MySQL ?

Thank you!

---

**Update 2013/1/7:**

I want to show the only one best `answer`(the max vote answer) if exists. The answer from @Brian Hoover works fine ONLY under MySQL.

Maybe there is not a SQL working fine under all databases.

Comment: The answer is different depending on if you need to get the answerID or not.  It's simpler if you don't need to return that field

Comment: How to get the result in one SQL ? Full answer record not only max(vote).

Comment: What happens if there is a tie?

Comment: Also, the answer will be different depending on the database you are using.

Comment: Soemthing like this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f0ee/3)

Comment: without sub query, the columns not in grouping by is not correct. see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db287/1/0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```
SELECT answer.aid, answer.qid, answer.vote, answer.content
   FROM answer
   JOIN (
          SELECT qid, max(vote) vote FROM answer
          GROUP BY qid) AS max_answer
    ON answer.qid = max_answer.qid AND answer.vote = max_answer.vote
   where answer.qid in (1,2)
   GROUP BY answer.qid, answer.vote
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39bfe/9)

In this case, ties will be broken, pretty much at random, so only one record will show per questionID, but there is no guarantee that the answer chosen in the case of tie will be consistent

Comment: I want find the only one max(vote) answer if exists. So this is the best answer but only working at MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* FROM answer a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT qid, MAX(vote) AS max_vote
  FROM answer
  WHERE qid IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY qid) b
  ON a.qid = b.qid
  AND a.vote = b.max_vote
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0db39/6)

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select a.*
from answer a
where a.qid in (1, 2) and
      a.vote = (select max(vote) from answer a2 where a2.qid = a.qid)
```

This version would work in any database.  There are other ways to express this in standard SQL:

```
select a.*
from answer a join
     (select a.qid, max(vote) as maxvote
      from answer a
      where a.qid in (1, 2)
      group by a.qid
     ) asum
     on a.qid = asum.qid and a.vote = asum.maxvote
```

Notice that I put the `where` restriction in the subquery.  Otherwise, the query will need to do the group by on all the rows in answer, then join, then do the filtering.

Comment: @Gordon Your query is nice as usual. I tried out [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f0ee/3) seems to match Op's expected answer unless I am missing something there.. But surely what I tried is too simple for OP to question there though..

Comment: @BrianHoover . . . I'm not sure what your comment is referring to.  The question does not describe what to do in the case of ties.  Returning all maximum values is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The question does say "find the max(vote) answer," not "find the max(vote) answers"  Putting on my experienced developer hat, that means that the original question was for one row per question, not an unlimited number of rows per question.  I agree that it's ambiguous, but this is the type of trap that developers and product manager fall into, as you well know.

Comment: @BrianHoover . . . Good for you for recognizing an ambiguous question and knowing what questions to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
select aid,qid,max(vote),content
from
(select a.aid aid,a.qid qid,a.vote vote,a.content content 
from question q join
answer a
on (a.qid = q.qid)
order by 3 desc) tbl
group by qid;
```

Comment: This is using a MySQL (mis)feature called Hidden Columns, where non-aggregated columns are included in the `select` but not the `group by` clause.  The value of "aid" and "content" are arbitrary, and not necessary the values associated with the maximum value.

Comment: Yeah, this works on mysql. But @GordonLinoff answer is better.

Comment: @imxylz . . . This may happen to work on a particular data set.  However, it is not guaranteed to work in all cases.  You should check out what happens with hidden columns in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
  select qid, aid ,vote
  from answers where qid  in ( 123, 456 ) 
  order by vote desc 
) aaa
group by qid
```

If some records have has same vote, this works too.

Comment: check the answer of @ajith-sasidharan. This works only at mysql.